# Save data on image that is hard to see by human but recognizable by device with camera

Tags: image, qr-code, steganography

Anyone has any good idea to save data on image that is hard to see by human but recognizable by device with camera?
Number on licence plate can be recognized by computer; QR code can be recognized by our smart phone. They are all visible to human also. What if I had no space to show my QR code beside my ad picture? Visualead has developed something like bellow, which saves space of the QR code.

[image: Visualead's QR code picture]

Can we do it deeper, making the QR code nearly invisible? Use something like special color?

Comment: However interesting this may be, [questions on this site should describe specific problems and be programming related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). For example, the difference between "I have difficulty in implementing the algorithm for encoding this QR" vs "let's come up with a new QR idea". According to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), open-ended questions that invite discussion and opinionated responses are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Reti43! I'll try at Super User or somewhere else. Should I delete this question at stackoverflow?